# Find Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\left(x-\pi\right)^n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

This is not a homework problem (I'm on break, so time for my own studies).

Find the radius of convergence of
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\left(x-\pi\right)^n.
\end{align}

I have found
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\left(x-\pi\right)^n}{2^n}}{\displaystyle\frac{\left(x-\pi\right)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{2^{n+1}\left(x-\pi\right)^n}{2^n\left(x-\pi\right)^{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{\left(x-\pi\right)}=\frac{2}{x-\pi}.
\end{align}
Is this right?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't found the radius of convergence -- it's a constant, not variable. The radius of convergence $r$ of a power series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n(x - x_0)^n$ is such that $1/r = \lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$, assuming the limit exists. In your case, $x_0 = \pi$ and $a_n = 1/2^n$. Thus

$$\frac{1}{r} = \lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Hence, $r = 2$.

---

Taking another look at your work, it seems like you attempted to compute directly the radius of convergence using $r = \lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n/a_{n+1}|$, but in that case your choice of $a_n$ is incorrect -- it should be $1/2^n$, the $n$th coefficient of your power series. Then $|a_n/a_{n+1}| = 2$ for all $n$, which implies $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |a_n/a_{n+1}| = 2$. So again, $r = 2$.

Comment: This makes sense, I'm glad I'm studying it. Thanks for an exceptional answer, as always!

Comment: @kobe what am I doing wrong if anything. Is this just a personal flavor thing?

Comment: @Zach466920 The radius of your interval $[\pi - 2, \pi + 2]$ is $2$, not $\pi$.

Comment: I am reading a paper that states I may find the radius of convergence $R$ of a power series, as you have written it, with $$ R=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|a_n\right|}{\left|a_{n+1}\right|},  $$ as long as the limit exists. So if I have a power series that looks like $$ 1+\frac{x}{b}+\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^3+\cdots $$ I would end up with a $b$, the apparent ROC on top, instead of the bottom with the ratio test inverted? So, as my $b=2,$ i.e. $\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^n=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$, as you have shown, my ROC is indeed $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @jm324354 I addressed this in the comment below. Please read it first.

Comment: My apologies, was writing the above and didn't see you had replied.

Comment: @kobe thanks, was just having a moment with that radius thing

Comment: @jm324354 just to let you know, I added a remark in my answer that I  gave in the comments.

Comment: @kobe thanks! Makes sense now

Comment: @kobe Woops, I was waiting earlier because it told me I had to wait ~3 mins but then forgot. Thanks for the reminder! You certainly deserve the points.

Answer (score 1):

You did it upside down ;). Just invert your final answer, which is correct. Solve for the radius...
$$-1 \le {{x-\pi} \over {2}} \le 1$$
$$-2 \le {x-\pi} \le 2$$
$$ \pi-2 \le x \le \pi+2$$
Looks like the radius is $2$.

Comment: See that's what I thought! I am reading a paper right now that's telling me the radius of convergence for the power series is given by $$ R=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|a_n\right|}{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}, $$ as long as the limits exists. I was so confused reading it because that's not at all what I recall from Calc. II.

Comment: @jm324354 that's weird my book has it the inverted way, ignore most of what I said, apparently you can do it that way.

Comment: No you're certainly right about finding the ROC, i.e. I have it inverted. I'm just looking it over again, and I think what they were saying is right, it's just supposed to come out in the numerator this way  and in the opposite, as Kobe has done it, it appeared in the denominator. I'll ask to make sure

Comment: @jm324354 your formula for $R$ is correct (assuming that limit exists), but your choice of $a_n$ is incorrect. The term $a_n$ is $1/2^n$, so $|a_n|/|a_{n+1}| = 2$. So $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|/|a_{n+1}| = 2$, showing that $R = 2$.

Comment: @kobe I see now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the ratio test, but you have the formula inverted. It should be $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {|a_{n+1}|} {|a_n|} $. As in, the $|a_{n+1}|$ term should be on $\textit {top}.$

Zach's answer is not correct. The radius of convergence is not $\pi$. Rather, the power series is $\textit centered$ at $\pi$. The interval of convergence (which is the center plus/minus the radius of convergence) is $[2-\pi, 2+\pi]$ (make sure to check the endpoints for convergence as well).